# Google Cloud Messaging Server side registration?

Tags: java, android, spring, google-cloud-messaging

I have tried registering for GCM from Android and it works fine.

Is there any way I can register for GCM from server side using the gcm-server API?

Answer (score 1):

The mechanic behind GCM message receiving is there is a process running in the background waiting for those messages sent from GCM server before passing to the specific app registered. In the other words, you need **a platform** to make GCM works or it has no way to receive a GCM message.

So the answer is no. You cannot register your server with GCM since there is no mechanic to send those message back to your server. So far there are only three platforms that support GCM: Android, iOS and Chrome.

Comment: So you mean to say there is no way i can get gcm key while doing registration from spring platform or any other apart from android ,ios and chrome.

Comment: Yes there is no way. You need to do the proper way to register to GCM server from Android, iOS or Chrome directly and get a registration token back. And it is the only token that you can work with to send a message to the client.